# Trying to add text to video, and the ouput only shows the final text, video never plays

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a project like this:

[image]

The 3D scene was just created it only contains a 2D text. it should play for 2 seconds, and then the video, but instead the text plays for the whole video. Even if I remove the text, then it will just be a greish video window, and the video I am trying to load never plays.

I need to close Blender, and add the video from fresh, but from the moment I play with a camera, my video is gone.

I am new to blender, so I guess there is something I am missing.

In the preview everything looks fine, and when I move my mouse around, the video looks fine. But when I click render, the output file will only contain the text.

I have also set the background of the text scene to transparent, and same behaviour.

Even If I remove that text scene, and then move the video to the start, then from that point on only that text scene will play. See:

[image]

If I start a project and just add this video, then it is fine.

Comment: the text is shown for 60 frames right? Because framerate is 30 fps and the  duration of the text is 2 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

In the project scene settings called Properties panel, make sure that you have Post Production > Sequencer active. Otherwise the VSE will not be rendered.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the alpha over doesn't seem to work but looks good otherwise:

[image: transparent key failure]

Then check the strip properties, press the N-key and select the following strip "Blend" type: Alpha Over or Over Drop

[image: VSE blend type]

You should find that the strip is multiplied with the background correctly then. The default blend setting is "replace" which will ignore whatever is below the active strip.

[image: Alpha over VSE blend type]

Answer (score 0):

An additional issue might be that Blender cannot find the video strip. If you have renamed the video at its original location after having imported it to the Video Editor, the Video Editor would still display the video normally. However, rendering it would fail, as Blender seems to try to access the video file at the location it has been imported from and cannot find it. (Got this issue with Blender 3.6.)